# Get length of unsigned char*

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, unsigned-char

Hi i am trying to get the length of unsigned char*, it is a pointer to a array witch means i cant use sizeof. I cant cast it to char* then do strlen() either, seeing as it contains null bytes in the middel of the string. What other way is there to do this?

```
stream.open("test.txt");
stream.write((char*)c, Length of the string); // How do i find Length of the string
stream.close();
```

Comment: You can't. Wherever you got the `unsigned char*` should also provide the length of the referenced sequence.

Comment: You should be able to answer this yourself, simply by looking the code and its documentation that gave you this `unsigned char*` in the first place. Nobody here knows where it came from.

Comment: If all you have is a `char *` and the string might contain null characters, then there is no way to determine its length.  If you want more help, please submit a [mre].

Comment: How do you know that the first null byte doesn't signal the end of the string? Maybe that's the actual end of the string!

Comment: i have the orginal size of the data it cannot be less than it

Comment: Reminder, `char *` is actually a pointer to a *single* character.  The size of `char *` is the size of a pointer, usually `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(char *)`.  A nul terminated string, a.k.a. C-String, is actually an array of characters that contains a nul character and the length *of the text*, is the number of characters before the nul is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: You can't.**

---

> Hi i am trying to get the length of unsigned char*

Presumably, you mean the length of the array it points to.

> it is a pointer to a array witch means i cant use sizeof.

That's right.

> I cant cast it to char* then do strlen() either, seeing as it contains null bytes in the middel of the string.

Okay, so it's not a null-terminated C-string. Null termination is the way to *calculate* a C-string's length when you haven't stored it by other means.

> What other way is there to do this?

None. You'll have to store it by other means. For example, pass it around with the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> it is a pointer to a array

To use precise terminology: It is a pointer to an unsigned char. That unsigned char may be an element of an array.

> i cant use sizeof. ...  it contains null bytes in the middel of the string. What other way is there to do this?

Seeing as you know that there is an array, the solution is simple: use `sizeof` on the array instead of the pointer.